# Visual Studio 2012 compiler alternative on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11

I switched to Linux a few days ago and I'm stuck on porting my project. For some reason, no matter if I'm using clang++ or gcc 4.8, the compiler complaints about using a atomic with a vector from the GLM-Library (something like that: `atomic<glm::vec3>`). I tried to set `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11`, which gcc doesn't accept and g++/clang++ don't care about. I know that it's not my code, because it worked on Windows with Visual Studio 2012.

So now my question is, if there is a good alternative to the VS2012 compiler, so that my code gets to work? I also thought to try gcc 4.9, but I really have no idea how to get that.

clang error message:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/atomic|166|error: exception specification of explicitly defaulted default constructor does not match the calculated one|
```

g++ error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/atomic|167|error: function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() [with _Tp = glm::detail::tvec3<float>]’ defaulted on its first declaration with an exception-specification that differs from the implicit declaration ‘std::atomic<glm::detail::tvec3<float> >::atomic()’|
```

Comment: Please add the compiler output (i.e. the error message) to your question.

Comment: I edited the question. It looks like glm::vec3 isn't trivially copyable, but why did it work on vs2012?

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to your question, but gcc 4.8 definitely accepts `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glm::vec3` is a typedef to some specialization of `tvec<float, T>`. `tvec` has a user-provided assignment operator, so it is not trivially copyable and therefore cannot be used with `std::atomic`. The code compiles with VS2012 because Microsoft's standard library implementation doesn't diagnose instantiations of `std::atomic<T>` for non-TriviallyCopyable `T`. As with any undefined behavior, the fact that it compiles does not imply that it works.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I would never have found that bug if I haven't swichted.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::atomic<glm::vec3> // sizeof(...) == 12
```

This specialization does not exist. There are only specialization of bool, integral types and pointer types provided by the STL. Either you have to specialize it on your own, or have to use another solution for your specific problem. Please note, that `std::atomic<glm::vec3>` may not be `TriviallyCopyable` on your platform (because of the size it may nowhere be trivially copyable). This means, that a mutex is used to synchronize this. For a vector I am really sure, that there is no way to trivially copy it. So you may use a pair of vector and mutex instead.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, it is not the std::vector, but the glm::vec3. And std::atomic<glm::vec3> should work, because glm::vec3 is indeed trivially copyable and it worked on vs2012, as is said.

Comment: `glm::vec3 a; std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;` This outputs 12 at my computer and thus is not trivially copyable. Why it works on Windows? I don't know. The trivially copyable thing does not raise the compiler problem, but the non existing template specialization does.

Comment: "worked on vs2012" ... Visual Studio is not a shining beacon of standards compliance, but often has missing features or other problems.